# Bug report: Using bold markup next to a quotation will not render the text as bold in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I just tried adding this comment to an answer:

> "You should use **double** instead of **double**"?

Instead, it showed up as:

> "You should use **double** instead of **double**"?

It looks like if you use two asterisks `**` next to a double quote, it will render the double quotes as literals. This applies for double quotes that appear both before and after the asterisks. This also only occurs for comments, not for questions and answers.

Comment: "**You** should use **double** instead of **double**"?

Comment: Known and intended bug. See [Inconsistency in styled comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3185/inconsistency-in-styled-comments) and others in the Related sidebar.

Comment: “ **You** could simply use a *hair space* (U+200A)  after the opening and before the closing quote **!** ”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added ' and " as whitelisted delimiters for bold and italic in mini-markdown.