# Italics and quotation marks in comments

Tags: support, comments, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using bold or italics in comments with single or double quotes does not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112050/using-bold-or-italics-in-comments-with-single-or-double-quotes-does-not-work)

I've just tried to write a comment with a content like

> “foo *and bar*”.

but failed to do so. Apparently in the sequence `*”` the asterisk won't be identified as marking the end of a comment. Using `<i>…</i>` doesn't seem to work in comments either. Notice that these are typographic quotation marks, using straight ones works well enough. Still, I believe there *should* be a way to enter a comment written and formatted like the one above.

Do you know of any? If not, do you think this is more likely a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)?

Comment: Test: `“foo *and bar*”`: “foo *and bar*”, `“foo _and bar_”`: “foo _and bar_”.

Comment: So, you're using curly quotes, right? Then: [Italics markup not working in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64706/italics-markup-not-working-in-comments). (All should be fine [for regular quotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78119/bug-report-using-bold-markup-next-to-a-quotation-will-not-render-the-text-as-bo), "and *indeed*".)

Comment: @Arjan, seems I somehow missed that question when searching for this. Sorry for the duplicate, feel free to close.