# Inconsistent parsing of Markdown wrt italics and punctuation in posts and comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

On Language and Usage sites, proper punctuation is sometimes important. Consider the following source:

```
“*bla*”, *bla*! *bla*… (*bla*), [*bla*], *bla*/*bla* and |*bla*|!
```

In question and answer posts, almost all *bla*-s properly italicize:

> “*bla*”, *bla*! *bla*… (*bla*), [*bla*], *bla*/*bla* and |*bla*|!

Only the one found after a slash is not rendered as one might expect, but it doesn't matter much as the slash should be avoided anyway.

However in comments (and on the chat), this same source yields something completely different:

> “*bla*”, *bla*! bla*… (*bla), [*bla*], bla*/*bla and |*bla*|!

Please make it consistent! To learn markdown's bloody edge cases is a pain, having to learn them twice is painfully stupid.

`“*italics in asymmetric quotes*”` (or `„*kursiv in Anführungszeichen*”`, `*ellipsis*…`, etc.) is a common combination. It works in posts but not in comments.

Comment: The fact you cannot italicize inside words is consistent, and I have no problem with that.

Comment: Punctuation symbols have special treatment in both, but different treatments. I believe there is no good reason for this. The `|bla|` example was there to show that it also happens with some ascii punctuation characters. Btw, it's painful as well in the chat (similar to comment's markdown).

Comment: @TimStone: this is linked to the unexpected rendering after the slash (and is again somewhat consistent in both markdowns). This is orthogonal to the issue reported here.

Comment: You're right, my apologies.

Comment: @Doorknob: Your font might not distinguish `"` and `“`? If you want ascii characters to test with, use for example `|` or `+`, they are inconsistently handled.

Comment: |*this is a test*| |this *is a* test| |*test*| EDIT: Oh, now it's not working.

Comment: Related: [Bug report: Using bold markup next to a quotation will not render the text as bold in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78119/210346), [Italics and quotation marks in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146401/210346)

Comment: Most of these while be supported from the next build on; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64706/italics-markup-not-working-in-comments.

Comment: “*bla*”, *bla*! *bla*… (*bla*), [*bla*], *bla*/*bla* and |*bla*|!